# Error in LWC test: LWC1127: Invalid directive "$lwc:if" on element <template>

Tags: lightning-web-components, lwc-jest

I have the following in my html template using `lwc:if`:

```
<template lwc:if={showSpinner}>
    <lightning-spinner alternative-text="Loading" size="large"></lightning-spinner>
</template>
```

And here is my test:

```
describe('c-aggriddatatablev2', () => {
    afterEach(() => {
        // The jsdom instance is shared across test cases in a single file so reset the DOM
        while (document.body.firstChild) {
            document.body.removeChild(document.body.firstChild);
        }
    });

    it('TODO: test case generated by CLI command, please fill in test logic', () => {
        // Arrange
        const element = createElement('c-aggriddatatablev2', {
            is: Aggriddatatablev2qed
        });

        // Act
        document.body.appendChild(element);

        // Assert
        // const div = element.shadowRoot.querySelector('div');
        expect(1).toBe(1);
    });
});
```

But I receive the error:

```
LWC1127: Invalid directive "$lwc:if" on element <template>.
```

I've looked everywhere online and found nothing on what the problem is. Any idea?

Comment: If you're using a older project, it's possible LWR is out of date. Try using `npm i` to update your project's packages, and see if that helps?

Comment: @sfdcfox nope, that didn't work.

Comment: I have the same issue - `npm i`, `npm update` didn't make any difference.

It doesn't look like https://github.com/salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest has had any recent updates that would cover lwc:if

Comment: Tell a lie - once I had updated my `sfdx-lwc-jest` reference in `package.json`, to the right version: `"@salesforce/sfdx-lwc-jest": "^1.4.0"`, and ran `npm install` all was good.   Prior to that it wouldn't take me up the version number.  My lack of spotting the change in the git repo was probably because it's covered in a package dependency.